# Can't load assets in an app which is served with a rewrite on Vercel

Tags: javascript, vercel, turborepo

### Problem

Assets are not loading (HTTP 404) for the app that is being served with a rewrite.

### Explanation

Hi! I'm using turborepo to create a website. I have two different apps (`RootApp` and a `SideProject`). Both of them are deployed to Vercel. I've configured the `RootApp` to be served on a custom domain. I've been following [this blog](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-serve-multiple-projects-under-a-single-domain) post trying to configure the rewrites.

`RootApp` is an Astro project and it has a `vercel.json` with this source:

```
// vercel.json

{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/projects/<SideProjectName>",
      "destination": "<SideProjectProdUrl>"
    }
  ]
}
```

`SideProject` is a Vite/React app. I have configured it to have a `basePath` like this

```
// vite.config.js

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/projects/<SideProjectName>/',
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

`RootApp` is being served fine, but when I'm navigating to `<custom-domain>/projects/<SideProjectName>` only the HTML request works. Both asset requests for `CSS` and `JS` fail with `404`. They request `<custom-domain>/projects/<SideProjectName>/assets/...`

What do I need to configure for assets to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue I had to add a redirect for the assets.

```
// vercel.json

{
  "redirects": [
    {
      "source": "/projects/<SideProjectName>/assets/:filePath",
      "destination": "<SideProjectProdUrl>/assets/:filePath",
      "permanent": true
    }
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/projects/<SideProjectName>",
      "destination": "<SideProjectProdUrl>"
    }
  ]
}
```